# Masking a web page

Tags: javascript, css, mask

Example:

[image: example]

The area with the red border is where you can fully see through the mask. Everything else is grayscaled and partially hidden with opacity or transparent white background.

One thing I tried is to make a class for each selectable area with a grayscale filter and lower opacity. Then I apply this class on all areas but the selected one. But this doesn't work well this nested zones because some of the areas become less opaque than others.

Any advice on how could I implement this?

---

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azoMVJ)

Works as expected only on `#footer`, because it doesn't have parent or children areas that are selectable

Comment: Can you put some codes if you want help? ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply an `highlighted` class to the chosen element like so

```
.highlighted {
  border: 1px red solid;
  outline: 999em solid rgba(255,255,255, .75);
}
```

A wide outline will cover all other elements.

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emOXRJ

Comment: This doesn't grey out the surrounding area though.

Comment: I applied the class to an heading element. if he applies the class to a specific div he can obtain the effect.

Comment: Nice idea with the outline, I think making the highlighted window fixed is what the @onetrickpony was looking for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPKgra

Comment: well, in such case, instead of using an empty element you could just style a pseudolement, e.g. `body::before`

Comment: Can't use the greyscale filter here, but that's pretty clever! Also it appears that you need to bring the element in front for this work with divs - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNbdYe

Answer (score 2):

Add an z-index higher then the overlay to the element you want too focus on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a straightforward way to do this. One idea would be to have four block elements around the edges of the element in question that have a semi-transparent fill colour, however you will have to measure and position these in JavaScript, and you'll have to take scrolling into account also. Before attempting this, I would look for a library that already offers this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a full sized div with a transparent grey background and a z-index higher than the rest of your site:

```
#cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and then on the zone you want to be fully visible you set an even higher z-index:

```
#other_content{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    border: red medium solid;
}
```

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czLppg9m/)